# How can I insert hundreds of thousands records using single Insert statement?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to insert thousands of records in one table with specific values. Just one condition that two columns have dynamic values.

Business logic: I need to insert specific value for all the websites of all the clients. One client can have one or more than websites.

If I want to write static SQL then my SQL will have more than 100k records to insert!

The records I want to insert into the table `website_preferences` as

```
INSERT into website_preferences ( cid, website_id, key, value, is_preview, updated_by, updated_on, created_by, created_on, details )
VALUES ( DYNAMIC_CID, DYNAMIC_WEBSITE_ID, 'NEIGHBORHOOD_GOOGLE_PLACES', 'airport, gas_station, supermarket, gym', 123, NOW(), 123, NOW(), NULL )
```

`websites` table have the cid and website_id with other metadata.

This query will give me up to hundreds of thousands of records:

```
SELECT w.id,w.cid FROM websites w WHERE deleted_by IS NOT NULL
```

How can I fetch the `cid` and `id` (website id ) from the `websites` table and associate to the insert statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for an INSERT ... SELECT:

```
INSERT into website_preferences (cid, website_id, key, value, is_preview, updated_by, updated_on, created_by, created_on, details)
SELECT w.id, w.cid, 'NEIGHBORHOOD_GOOGLE_PLACES', 'airport, gas_station, supermarket, gym', 123, NOW(), 123, NOW(), NULL
FROM websites w 
WHERE deleted_by IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Not sure why it is not working, id - cid pair not get inserted properly

Comment: No error, just the records not get inserted as expected.

Comment: So what do you expect? And what happens?

Comment: It was my mistake of WHERE condition in SELECT. Working fine as expected.

Answer (score 3):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into website_preferences ( cid, website_id, key, value, is_preview, updated_by, updated_on, created_by, created_on, details )
    select ws.cid, ws.website_id, 'NEIGHBORHOOD_GOOGLE_PLACES', 'airport, gas_station, supermarket, gym', 123, NOW(), 123, NOW(), NULL
    from websites ws
    where ws.deleted_by is not null;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

```
INSERT into website_preferences ( cid, website_id, key, value, is_preview, updated_by, updated_on, created_by, created_on, details )
SELECT w.id,w.cid,'NEIGHBORHOOD_GOOGLE_PLACES', 'airport, gas_station, supermarket, gym', 123, NOW(), 123, NOW(), NULL FROM websites w WHERE deleted_by IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Not sure why it is not working, id - cid pair not get inserted properly